# ADFS Server 2016: MSIS9611 Grant Type not supported

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, adfs

Let me preface this by saying I have never set up an ADFS before, im just a developer so please be gentle lol.

We have an ADFS Server 2016 install and we are looking to be able to send credentials to do a silent authentication.

previously we were doing

```
ar = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync( strAppURI, strClientIdentifier, new Uri( strClientReturnURI ), new PlatformParameters( PromptBehavior.Auto ) );
```

this would allow for the ADFS to pop a login screen.  We no longer want to do that.  The application we have is now gathering the clients username and password and we want to pass it to ADFS.

This is the updated call

```
ar2 = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync( strAppURI, strClientIdentifier, credential );
```

Where credential is a UserPasswordCredential from Microsoft.IdentityModel

The issue is, I am receiving a response as follows:

"MSIS9611: The authorization server does not support the requested 'grant_type'. The authorization server only supports 'authorization_code' or 'refresh_token' as the grant type."

My assumption is that something is not configured properly.  I did some searches through the site and could not find a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

There are four different flows in OAuth as per [this](https://alexbilbie.com/guide-to-oauth-2-grants/).

Which flow are you using and what grant type are you setting?

ADFS 4.0 supports them all. I've documented the Postman flows [here](https://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/search/label/Postman).